# How to Implement a Subscription Cost Reduction for Existing iOS App Users?

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

I have an iOS app with three subscription plans: monthly, 3 months, and annual. I'm considering reducing the subscription prices, but I'm unsure how to handle this transition for my existing customers.

1. How does Apple handle price reductions for auto-renewable subscriptions? Will my existing customers be automatically switched to the new price, or will they be prompted to agree to the new price?
2. How should I communicate this change to my current subscribers to ensure a smooth transition and maintain trust?
3. Are there any best practices or pitfalls I should be aware of when reducing subscription prices on the App Store?

Ideally I want to provide the reduced price for existing customers to value their trust.